# What happened to the ignore option in the mouseover on the tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

In the old pop-up when you hovered over a tag in the question list, there was a link to add to favorites and a link to ignore the tag.  In the new design of this pop-up, there's a star to add to favorites, but there is no icon or link to ignore.

Could we add an ignore link?  I always liked this when someone asks a question about an obscure technology I don't work with.  It was very easy to just add that question to the ignore list and move on.

I miss it.

Comment: Yep this will be nice re-feature.

Comment: I don't know how much more I can publicize this except to keep putting a bounty on it.  I would think it would be easy to get this feature back in.

Comment: Maybe it was removed for a reason.. surprised nobody from "the team" said anything yet. Anyhow the bounty and 23 votes should be enough to draw attention. :-)

Comment: I bet it was removed for the same reason that anything making it too easy to delete files from your disk might get removed. The down side of accidentally clicking it was too high.  Last time I tried to search for a java question, and I had the "java" tag ignored, I still got lots of java question results, just not the ones that were properly tagged.  But they appeared and then quickly disappeared. Talk about weird.

Comment: Well, if it *was* removed for a reason, it should be pretty easy for someone to pop in here and share.  Ten weeks and three bounties later, there's nothing.

Comment: @Warren surely it's easy to unignore a tag that you've accidentally ignored though. If not maybe that should be another feature request.

Comment: main reason we removed this was to avoid a cluttered UI

Comment: @waffles: just put a "mute sound" button behind the word `followers`, that wouldn't clutter and is pretty intuitive...

Comment: So there is a "faq", "info", and "top users" link, but we can't just get an "ignore tag" put in there?  There's plenty of room.  It helps promote the fact that this functionality is available, and makes it easy to ignore.  The other option is to go to the right column, scroll down through my whole list of ignored tags, and actually type the name of the tag in - hoping I get the spelling right.

Comment: Yes a mute button to ignore the tag would go nicely at the top beside the number of followers or at the bottom beside the links without making things too cluttered IMO.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

We're looking at having a tri-state for the star:

- star grey: not favorite (default)
- star gold: favorite
- [Ghost Busters CROSSOUT symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_symbol) in red: ignored

(⃠ or a plain old × I guess)

click it to change between the three?

Comment: Sounds good to me!  When there's something strange, in your neighborhood.  Who you gonna call?  Jeff Atwood!

Comment: @Erick, just in case you missed this: this has been implemented. And some nice screenshots in [Idea For Ignored Tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114124/idea-for-ignored-tags/114126#114126).

Comment: I don't see these options anymore: were they removed again for some reason?

Comment: This is really not intuitive.  The user doesn't know what the star does without looking at the tooltip.  I think a lot more users would be using this feature if they knew it existed.

Comment: Three state is not intuitive. As people already pointed out... I strongly recommend you return to the old, plain-simple "ignore" (tag) link at the bottom of the popup frame. I came here because I was searching the SO to find out how can I ignore tag like I used to do before...

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure what the reason that this isn't implemented is, but since there doesn't appear to be a route to update the ignored list in the same way as the star updates the favorites list, it's not as simple as just dropping in the link.

It still seemed like people might find it useful to have though, so since you hadn't gotten too much feedback on this yet I went ahead and wrote a userscript that adds this functionality. In addition to the favorite star, there's now an ignore radioactivity symbol*:

[image: Tag popup with link to ignore the tag selected]

Once I'm more confident that it works reliably (and I successfully avoid getting scolded for scraping the user preferences tab) I'll write up a post for it over on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/). In the meantime, if you want to test it out, here's the information:

> [install / update script](https://github.com/tms/StackExchangeTests/raw/master/SETagPopupFix.user.js) – [view source](https://github.com/tms/StackExchangeTests/blob/master/SETagPopupFix.user.js)

<sub>*I'm open to suggestions on this one. I wanted a "No Entry" unicode symbol originally, but the ones that I found didn't seem to be well-supported.</sub>

Comment: +1 Brilliant!  Now, I don't understand why this is too cluttered, but whatever.  I love it.  Thanks!