# Adding tags as ignored, from tag pages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

When I subscribe to a new StackExchange site, I usually go to the Tags page and look for existing (and possibly popular) tags to add as favorite, but also to look for subjects that I'll probably ignore systematically.

However, while it is easy to add a tag as favorite by *starring* it, the only way I know to add a tag as ignored is typing its name in the Ignored Tags section of the site's homepage. If I'm lucky, I soon get an autocompletion while typing, but IMO even so that's a waste of time.

*Old question:* wouldn't it be better to have an "ignore tag" or "add as ignored" link somewhere in the tag mouseover and/or in the Tagged Questions page?

**EDIT:** I just learned about the new [tri-state star](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/what-happened-to-the-ignore-option-in-the-mouseover-on-the-tags/93630#93630) from the [Recent feature changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange/59446#59446) page. I am happy about that since it solves my problem (I was tempted to answer this question with that), but now I wonder if this solution is clear enough for new users. In fact, even if the feature is explained with popup text over the star, I probably wouldn't have noticed if it weren't for the Recent changes post. I'm not asking this as a proper new question, since it is very similar to the original one anyway.

**"New" question:** Should the tri-state star in the tag mouseover be better advertised, and/or should we have other ways to ignore tags, like a link in the Tagged Questions page?

Comment: I hope my English is at least readable; please feel free to improve it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happened to the ignore option in the mouseover on the tags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/what-happened-to-the-ignore-option-in-the-mouseover-on-the-tags)

Comment: Thanks @Jon for spotting that. Anyway, I'm not asking that an `ignore` link should appear *specifically in the mouseover*: if that's "too cluttered", as people state in comments to that question, I would be totally be OK with a small, almost hidden link in the Tagged Questions page...

Answer (score 2):

tag mostly working to find related question for our requirement. and it's not ignore from tag pages.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a very useful feature for experienced / knowledgeable users, but I also don't think I want it and don't think it would seriously be considered on being implemented by default because it may make things too unintuitive for new users, may result in accidents, and would take up screen real-estate.

Comment: I think it's very intuitive! A user's ignored tags are displayed on the right column on the homepage, just below the favorite ones and with the same emphasis.

Comment: As pointed out in the [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78528/162839) linked by Jon in a comment above, this used to be a feature. Apparently it was removed because it made the UI "too cluttered". I disagree; to me this is much more useful than the `top users` link.