# Add to favorite and ignored tags from tag's tooltip

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags, tag-watching

In the tag tooltip could be two "*links*" for adding to favorite tags and to ignored tags. User could more quickly add ignored or favorite tags.

[image: Tag Tooltip Mockup]

Comment: Actually, this was implemented just a few days ago. It's not intuitive, though. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/what-happened-to-the-ignore-option-in-the-mouseover-on-the-tags/93630#93630

Comment: I just tried to do this right now but the link was not there in the tooltip... :(

Comment: @LenielMacaferi look at first comment:)