# How to ignore specific tags from "Favorite Tags"

Tags: discussion, tags, ignored-tags, favorites-tab

I have a question regarding favorites tags. I have added `ruby` as my favorite tag. However, most of the people who want ask question on `ruby-on-rails` tag, they tag `ruby` as well.

So when I click on `ruby` tag, I see all the questions with `ruby-on-rails` as well.

I know there is way in search filter where you can ignore the tags that you don't want.

e.g. I want to list all the questions that are tagged `ruby` but want to ignore any question which is tagged `ruby` as well as `ruby-on-rails`. I can do this by tying `[ruby] -[ruby-on-rails]` in the search box.

**Question:**
How to implement this feature in my `favorites` tabs? Right now, I have `ruby` in my favorites tab which will also list the `ruby-on-rails` questions.

[THis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/95961/244809) link shows a promising answer but I cannot find those option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your ignored tags at `profile -> preferences` or on the right side of the page when listing questions:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. this will still show me ignored tab...but yeah, it will be kind of faded saying that question belongs to ignored tab.